# SD_WAKE_AFFINE flag but no SD_BALANCE_WAKE flag in linux scheduler

Tags: linux, scheduler

In my scheduler domains at both the levels (my arch has 2 levels of sd), SD_WAKE_AFFINE flag is set but SD_BALANCE_WAKE is not set. However, I can't see the use of WAKE_AFFINE in the fair scheduler without SD_BALANCE_WAKE flag set. can someone explain it?

Comment: After digging through the kernel code a bit, I found that SD_BALANCE_WAKE is passed as a function parameter (sd_flags) to the select_fair_rq_task() function when the task is woken up on a cpu. This function is generic in that it gets called even when a new task is forked or exec'ed. SD_BALANCE_WAKE flag in combination with SD_WAKE_AFFINE flag chooses the correct SD and thus the cpu for wake cases.